# Can anyone explain the expression present inside "range" function in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I am not able to understand the expression present inside range function.
How it is calculating the value as 1.

Have tried the same expression with multiple values in seperate but getting the output as 0

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate 
# alternate elements summation 
# using list comprehension + list slicing 

# initializing list  
test_list = [2, 1, 5, 6, 8, 10] 

# printing original list  
print("The original list : " + str(test_list)) 

# using list comprehension + list slicing 
# alternate elements summation 
res = [sum(test_list[i : : 2]) for i in range(len(test_list)//(len(test_list)//2))] 

# print result 
print("The alternate elements summation list : " + str(res)) 
Output :
The original list : [2, 1, 5, 6, 8, 10]
The alternate elements summation list : [15, 17]
```

Comment: `len(test_list)//(len(test_list)//2)` is a stupid way to write `2`, but with a bug - because if `test_list` has a length of 3, it actually returns 3 instead of 2.

Comment: I didn't get your point..

Comment: `len(test_list)//(len(test_list)//2)` always returns `2`, except when `len(test_list)` is `3`, then it returns `3`.